# Remove white line from Navbar-toggler when expanding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm wanting to remove a strange white line that appears at the bottom of a navbar in the header of my page. The header has a dark background, but when I click on the toggler button a strange white line appears at the bottom of the header.

You can see my webpage here:

[abdelp.github.io](https://abdelp.github.io)

In the image below is indicated the line that I don't know where is coming from and I want to remove:

[image]

the HTML index is just the bootstrap initial template and the navbar template

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Abdel Pérez</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="site-banner site-banner--dark">
      <div class="site-banner__inner anim anim-up anim-fade loaded">
        <div class="site-banner__content">
          <h1 class="site-banner__title">
            My Projects
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the css

```css
/* Header */

.header {
  background-color: #191a1d;
}

.site-banner--dark {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 50px));
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #191a1d;
}

.site-banner--dark .site-banner__title {
  color: #fff;
}

.site-banner--dark .site-banner__tagline,
.site-banner--dark .site-banner__subtitle {
  color: #ababab;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm telling you my personal opinion and the solution I got:**

This is most likely related to the browser's rendering engine. So we can call it a kind of bug, albeit partially.

- I have encountered such situations in many browsers while playing with the scale of SVGs.
- For the solution of this situation, superimposing the two elements is an excellent result.
- So instead of intersecting two elements, they must be nested 1px.
- I marked the required encodings for this as `/* Added */` in the CSS section of the snippet.
- If you want, you can test the fluency of the animation by running the snippet.

Good luck with.

```css
/* Header */

.header {
  background-color: #191a1d;
}

.site-banner--dark {
  /* Added */ margin-top: -1px;
  /* Added */ padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 50px));
}

.site-banner--dark {
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #191a1d;
}

.site-banner--dark .site-banner__title {
  color: #fff;
}

.site-banner--dark .site-banner__tagline,
.site-banner--dark .site-banner__subtitle {
  color: #ababab;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Abdel Pérez</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="site-banner site-banner--dark">
  <div class="site-banner__inner anim anim-up anim-fade loaded">
    <div class="site-banner__content">
      <h1 class="site-banner__title">
        My Projects
      </h1>
      <h2 class="site-banner__subtitle">
        <!-- For over 10 years I’ve been designing and developing websites. Below are some of my favourites. -->
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

<!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
```